# Shiny Download Manager ERROR: ‘file’ must be a character string or connection

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I'm working on a Shiny App to output a dataframe as a CSV. I keep getting this error: ERROR: ‘file’ must be a character string or connection

The content function works when using the fakefile() method but not the productionfile() method, which leads me to believe that the problem is there. The people_placer is a function from a sourced file which outputs a dataframe:

```
production_file <- reactive({
    people_placer(input$prod1title, input$prod2title, input$prod3title, 
input$googleform)
})

fakefile <- reactive({
  list1 <- c(“1”, “2", “3”)
  list2 <- c(“a”, “b”, “c”)
  testdf <- data.frame(list1, list2)
})

output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(

  filename = “production1.csv”,

  content = function(file) {
    write.csv(production_file(), file, row.names = TRUE)
  }
)
```

I'm expecting it to run and output the file given in production file, but it just throws that error.

Comment: If you add `browser()` immediately before `write.csv(...)` and look at both `production_file()` and `file`, do they look like you'd expect?

Comment: `file` appears as `tmpdata` whereas there is not value for `production_file()`

Comment: So *that* is your problem: `people_placer` is either not being called or not returning (as you assume it does).